# symfony2 fosuserbundle remember_me cookie aftre register

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, remember-me

In my registerAction i turned off the confirmation so if the user fills in the form correctly, it is authenticated.
Does anyone know how to create rememberme cookie so as the user can stay authenticated?

My security.yml:

```
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        success_handler: my.authentication.success_handler
        failure_handler: my.authentication.failure_handler
    logout:       true
    anonymous:    true
    remember_me:
        key:      %secret%
        path:     /
        domain:   ~            
        always_remember_me: true
        user_provider: fos_userbundle
```

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? There is an article on symfony.com covering your use case: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Comment: when the user registeres, the cookie isnt set